# I need an expression that only retrieves Alphabetic characters

Tags: regex

i have a string that contains alphanumeric characters, and i wish to retrieve only the certain Alpha characters example `"1P-I-CP6210-01"` OR `"1P-I-FIT6210-01"` currently I am using:

```
Substring([Cables.CableNo],CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo]) + 2, CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo],CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo])+3) - CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo]) - 6)
```

which returns `(-CP)` and `(-FIT)`, but I just need it to return `(CP)` and `(FIT)`.

Comment: What language are you using? This looks like SQL - if so, which database are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Hello, i was able to fix the issue by doing the following:

Substring([Cables.CableNo],CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo]) + 3, CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo],CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo])+3) - CharIndex('-',[Cables.CableNo]) - 7)